# How can I catch more detailed information about a reindexing error or when reindexing is stuck?

Tags: magento2, products, reindex, indexer, product-reindexing

The size of the catalog is about 70k products.
When reindexing sometimes it turns out `Could not acquire lock for index:catalog_category_product` and `Could not acquire lock for index:catalog_product_category` or only stuck in `INSERT INTO catalog_category_product_index_store2_tmp ('category_id', 'product_id', 'position', 'i..` (I got this from `SHOW PROCESS LIST` phpmyadmin).

there is no more detailed information about the error in the log files,
Are there ways to get more detailed information about the error or stuck?